# why does my print job fail? 15 page PDF, freezes on page 7

Tags: macos, printing

I'm trying to print a 15 page document from Lion wirelessly to my HP 1102w printer.

The first 6 pages print fine then it freezes half way through page 7, and I have to power the printer off/on for it to work again.  I tried printing just page 7 and that works so it doesn't appear to be the content of the page.

I'm wondering if maybe the printer is running out of memory or something.  Is it possible there's a setting somewhere that will cause the Mac to send the document slower or something?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Which printer driver are you using for the printer?

Comment: It’s been half a year since you asked, did you keep the PDF to see if it works, let’s say, with a newer version of the operating system?

Comment: @myhd No sorry, did not keep the doc.  This question is now pretty useless now, I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never figured this out, so there appears to be no answer.  I'm adding this 'correct' answer because I don't want to look like a douche who don't indicate 'correct' answers. :(

Answer (score 0):

If you think its buffer issue then try to print from page 1 to 6, then 7 to 10, then 11 to 15. You should have the options.

If you do not see:

[image]

Then click the *Show Details* in the print Dialogue
[image]

Comment: thx, I already did this, but I don't understand why it can't handle a 15 page PDF as one print job.